# How to override a method of an external library?

Tags: java

I want to suppress the stacktrace of a specific exception: org.everit.json.schema.ValidationException.

This particular exception is thrown a lot in our application, and I want to limit the performance hit.

I tried extending it with my own:

```
public class SuppressValidationException extends ValidationException {

  public SuppressEveritValidationException(Schema violatedSchema,
      Class<?> expectedType, Object actualValue) {
    super(violatedSchema, expectedType, actualValue);
  }

  public SuppressEveritValidationException(Schema violatedSchema, Class<?> expectedType,
      Object actualValue, String keyword) {
    super(violatedSchema, expectedType, actualValue, keyword);
  }

  @Override
  public Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

But when I catch the SuppressValidation, the ValidationException goes uncaught. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: "But when I catch the SuppressValidation, the ValidationException goes uncaught" - please provide a [mcve] to explain more clearly what you mean. Note that catching `SuppressValidationException` won't catch any instances of plain `ValidationException`... if something is using `throw new ValidationException(...)` how would you expect `SuppressValidationException` to come into play?

Comment: What performance hit are you hoping to minimise? It seems likely that you won't be able to stop the exception being thrown, all you can change is how you react to it when it is thrown.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suppose one reason I thought it would come into play is that if I have two catch blocks, Intellij throws a warning stating they are identical. So I was hoping since that one extends the other exception, it would be caught when the other is referenced.

Comment: "if I have two catch blocks, Intellij throws a warning stating they are identical" - well that would depend on the precise nature of the blocks. A catch block for ValidationException would catch SuppressValidationException, but not the other way round...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple wrapper around the class of this external library that actually throws this exception, just pass through any method calls to the one with the same name, and catch exceptions if appropriate and rethrow a simpler version.

Also, whether you actually log the stacktrace will also depend on your logging framework and it can probably also be configured to not do that.

Comment: In that case, won't I just be catching the original the exception, to just throw my own exception?

Comment: @techieIntern yes you would, but that would solve the issue in the only way I would know how. You’d basically write a proxy around the implementing class, possibly even using the same interface, to hide this from the rest of your code